# Flickering faces in Edit mode 2.83

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, faces

I have this issue from the 2.83 update. I tried a couple of things but nothing seems to fix it. Here is a short video of how it looks. [Video](https://gyazo.com/e6c8816d45efcdc1e6c1de1fa264e1bf)

Also if I move my mouse over the XYZ on the top right the faces become see-through even though the option is disabled. The see-through disappears when I move the camera around. You can see this at the very end of the video, although my mouse doesn't seem to pass the XYZ. It worked 100% of the time when I hovered over XYZ when I retested it.

Comment: it seems to be z-fight. Can you check on google and come back if it doesn't help?

Comment: Agreed, looks like z-fighting. Select all > mesh > clean up > merge-by-distance

Comment: Merge-By-Distance does not help. I do not have any overlapping faces as well.

Comment: I just played around with blender a bit more and I can't figure out a way to fix it. All my other projects have this issue as well, even ones that I haven't opened in years. [Example](https://gyazo.com/d3c6a58cbed2c05631842e8cd40cef93)

Comment: Nothing seems to work so I guess I will have to wait until next update. I start a new project, click the cube, go to edit mode and the issue is already there.

Answer (score 1):

If issue is not yet fixed, I would suggest to change viewport anti-aliasing to *Non anti-aliasing* from *Edit > Preferences - Viewport* tab

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same behavior and it came out of nowhere.

- Pixelated diagonals over faces
- Faces flickering from gray to orange when selected
- Strange see-through

I already worked in the same version of Blender (2.83.0) before on the same computer without this problem.

Solved it by uninstalling Blender and reinstalling version 2.83.2